# Simplified formula for duration of interest rate swap

Tags: interest-rate-swap, duration

Lets consider the simple interest rate swap instrument as 5-year maturity interest rate swap. I found an interesting simplification to calculate the duration of such swap as,

$\frac{\left(1 - e^{-r_t * T}\right)}{r_t}$

In above expression the $r_t$ is current level of interest rate and $T$ is the swap maturity i.e. in this case 5.

Could you please help to obtain explanation how the `duration` is an interest rate swap looks like this? Also, is such approximation is applicable only naive `fixed vs floating` interest rate swap?

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting approximation, I have not yet seen this one.

The PV of a fix-for-float IRS, in a single-curve-world, is:

$$
PV=\sum_i\Delta^{float}_iF_iD(t_i)-q\sum_j\Delta^{fix}_jD(t_j)=1-D(t_n)-q\sum_j\Delta^{fix}_jD(t_j)
$$

The first derivative w.r.t. a parallel shift is

$$
\frac{\partial PV}{\partial r}=t_nD(t_n)+q\sum_j\Delta_j^{fix} t_jD(t_j)
$$

From here, you can derive all sorts of simplifications, one being

$$
\frac{\partial PV}{\partial r}\approx t_n
$$

If we now take your formula and Taylor expand, we arrive at:

$$
\frac{1-e^{-r_nt_n}}{r_n}=\frac{1-\left(1-r_nt_n+O(r_n^2t_n^2)\right)}{r_n}\approx t_n
$$

Which yields a similar approximation result.