# Duration of interest rate swap - seek explanation from a previous post

Tags: interest-rate-swap, sensitivities

I have come across a Q&A about [the calculation of the duration of an interest rate swap](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/73965/simplified-formula-for-duration-of-interest-rate-swap) on this site.

In the Q&A, the derivative is calculated as:

$\frac{\partial PV}{\partial r}=t_nD(t_n)+q\sum_j\Delta_j^{fix} t_jD(t_j)$.

I don't understand what $r$ is in the equation above? Shouldn't the derivative be calculated as $\frac{\partial PV}{\partial q}$, assuming $q$ is the swap rate?

I have also read somewhere that sensitivity of an interest rate swap w.r.t. its swap rate is approximately life of the swap.

So, I should expect that $\frac{\partial PV}{\partial q}\approx t_n$, but it is stated in that Q&A that $\frac{\partial PV}{\partial r}\approx t_n$. Are they both equal? If they are indeed equal, why so?

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/49582/interest-rate-swap-pv01-vs-dv01/49585#49585 does this help?

Comment: @Attack68 Thanks for this reference. However still I failed to understand why only $t_n$ term stays in above expression. Am I missing something very trivial?

Comment: The duration of any stream of cashflows is the derivative w.r.t. a flat interest rate that you use for *discounting*. The most prominent example is the duration of a bond which is the derivative of the price w.r.t. the *yield*. In your swap we take the derivatve w.r.t. $r$ and not w.r.t. the fixed swap rate $q\,.$ On top of that we divide that derivative by the price: duration$=\partial_r PV/PV\,.$ Exercise: what is the duration of a single fixed cashflow when you discount with a continously compounded rate $r\,?$

Comment: @kurt to answer your question, I think that duration of such cash flow should be the time of that cashflow (e.g. ZCB) Hope this answer is correct

Comment: It is. And it explains why one calls it duration.

Comment: But how to fit that answer to my original question? In Swap, I have Fixed and Floating cashflows. For floating cashflow, I have duration as next reset date (from Floating rate bond). But for fixed cashflow, I have some other duration. Why then the net duration for Swap will be the same as life of the swap?

Comment: nobody claimed that duration is always the life of the trade. this is only the case for a single fixed cashflow.